# Odoo using new api how to update a many2many id using @api.onchange

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-view

Using  odoo  new  api  the @api.onchange and  @api.depends  how can  i  update a field in  a  many2many ,  where  the field  is  updated  by another  field not in the  many2many ... i.e

```
class  rates(model.Model):
    _name  = 'rates'
    a  = field.Integer(string = 'VALUE DEPENDED ON')
    many2many = -----  that  contains  field c  
    which  i  need  updated when  a  changes  above
```

Sample code  will  highly  help

Comment: I think you have to be more specific. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: what do you mean by field in many2many field ?

Comment: @LudwikTrammer  Kindly this  question  just is  based  on this  questions  that i  have  asked  here  on SO  ,    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286371/how-to-update-field-dynamicaly-in-a-many2many-relation-field-and-within-tree-vie

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286371/how-to-update-field-dynamicaly-in-a-many2many-relation-field-and-within-tree-vie?noredirect=1#comment56319723_34286371


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335376/odoo-throws-a-missingerror-on-treeview-second-line-record